# how can glFlush() affect rendering correctness?

Tags: opengl, cython

> Upon noticing that there were
>   unexpected artefacts in other OpenGL
>   programs, I did some digging and
>   discovered that you can upgrade the
>   OpenGL stack on Ubuntu:
>   https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa
>
> After updating, all GL rendering was
>   faster (my test programs below
>   ***doubled*** in speed!) and without artefacts.
>
> So to answer my own question: how can
>   glFlush() affect rendering
>   correctness? *when the drivers are
>   buggy.*

=== ***original question*** ===

or, more correctly, what is the fundamental bug with my classic untrendy non-shader-VBO-stuff?

```
    cdef struct xyz:
        float x, y, z

    cdef inline void _normal(xyz b,xyz a):
        glNormal3f(a.x-b.x,a.y-b.y,a.z-b.z)

    cdef inline void _draw_quad(xyz a,xyz b,xyz c,xyz d):
        glVertex3f(a.x,a.y,a.z)
        glVertex3f(b.x,b.y,b.z)
        glVertex3f(c.x,c.y,c.z)
        glVertex3f(d.x,d.y,d.z)

    cdef void _draw_grid(xyz a,xyz b,xyz c,xyz d):
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP)
        _draw_quad(a,b,c,d)
        glEnd()


    .... # main loop goes through my data array issuing the appropriate functions

    while self._buf.remaining() > 0:
        op = self._buf.read_char()
        if op == _COLOR:
            col = self._buf.read_rgb()
            #print col
            glColor3f(col.r,col.g,col.b)
        elif op in (_BOX,_GRID):                    
            tl,tr,br,bl,trb,brb,tlb,blb = self._buf.read_xyz(),self._buf.read_xyz(),\
                self._buf.read_xyz(),self._buf.read_xyz(),\
                self._buf.read_xyz(),self._buf.read_xyz(),\
                self._buf.read_xyz(),self._buf.read_xyz()
            if op == _BOX:
                #print "box",col
                glBegin(GL_QUADS)
                func = _draw_quad
            else:
                #print "grid",col
                func = _draw_grid
            _normal(tlb,tl)
            func(tl,tr,br,bl)
            _normal(tl,tr)
            func(tr,trb,brb,br)
            _normal(tr,tl)
            func(tl,tlb,blb,bl)
            _normal(tr,tl)
            func(tl,tlb,trb,tr)
            _normal(tl,tr)
            func(bl,blb,brb,br)
            _normal(tl,tlb)
            func(tlb,trb,brb,blb)
            if op == _BOX:
                glEnd()
            #glFlush()
        else:
            raise Exception("corrupt serialisation; got %x"%op)
```

if flush after each cube or wireframe, I get this ***CORRECT*** rendering:
[image: correct, with flush]

if I omit the flush - and I obviously don't want to be flushing, even if I am not treading the most optimal opengl path - then I get this ***INCORRECT*** rendering, and this is the bug I don't understand:
[image: incorrect, without flush]

For the curious, here is how `glutSolidCube` and wires do it: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#xbii4fg5bFw/trunk/FDS/trunk/SMV_5/source/glut-3.7.6/glut_shapes.c&q=glutSolidCube%20lang:c&sa=N&cd=4&ct=rc

Comment: are you using double buffering?

Comment: not explicitly; this is a normal gtk opengl canvas

Comment: did you check the result of glGetError ? maybe u have solved/dropped this since...

Comment: @rotoglup I had dropped it, but you inspire me to go back and check :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't say precisely why not calling `glFlush()` causes undesired results, but you may want to take a look at a question about the [difference between glFlush ad glFinish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143240/opengl-glflush-vs-glfinish) I asked some time ago. It may have some useful info.

As for solutions, perhaps try putting a `glFlush()` after you're done rendering the entire scene, as opposed to each cube.

Answer (score 1):

the glBegin / glEnd calls in the code sample are not property matched, and in some cases they are overlapping. glFlush will effectively force a glEnd, so that is the difference. I suspect the rendered output would be the same if you simply replaced glFlush with glEnd.

For example, this is one way to fix your code:

```
cdef struct xyz:
    float x, y, z

cdef inline void _normal(xyz b,xyz a):
    glNormal3f(a.x-b.x,a.y-b.y,a.z-b.z)

cdef inline void _draw_quad(xyz a,xyz b,xyz c,xyz d):
    glVertex3f(a.x,a.y,a.z)
    glVertex3f(b.x,b.y,b.z)
    glVertex3f(c.x,c.y,c.z)
    glVertex3f(d.x,d.y,d.z)

cdef void _draw_grid(xyz a,xyz b,xyz c,xyz d):
    _draw_quad(a,b,c,d)

.... # main loop goes through my data array issuing the appropriate functions

while self._buf.remaining() > 0:
    op = self._buf.read_char()
    if op == _COLOR:
        col = self._buf.read_rgb()
        #print col
        glColor3f(col.r,col.g,col.b)
    elif op in (_BOX,_GRID):                    
        tl,tr,br,bl,trb,brb,tlb,blb = self._buf.read_xyz(),self._buf.read_xyz(),\
            self._buf.read_xyz(),self._buf.read_xyz(),\
            self._buf.read_xyz(),self._buf.read_xyz(),\
            self._buf.read_xyz(),self._buf.read_xyz()
        if op == _BOX:
            #print "box",col
            glBegin(GL_QUADS)
            func = _draw_quad
        else:
            #print "grid",col
            glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP)
            func = _draw_grid
        _normal(tlb,tl)
        func(tl,tr,br,bl)
        _normal(tl,tr)
        func(tr,trb,brb,br)
        _normal(tr,tl)
        func(tl,tlb,blb,bl)
        _normal(tr,tl)
        func(tl,tlb,trb,tr)
        _normal(tl,tr)
        func(bl,blb,brb,br)
        _normal(tl,tlb)
        func(tlb,trb,brb,blb)
        glEnd()
        #glFlush()
    else:
        raise Exception("corrupt serialisation; got %x"%op)
```