# Choppy SDL+OpenGL animation when vsync is on

Tags: linux, opengl, sdl

```c
Uint32 prev = SDL_GetTicks();

while ( true )
{
    Draw();

    Uint32 now = SDL_GetTicks();
    Uint32 delta = now - prev;
    printf( "%u\n" , delta );
    Update( delta / 1000.0f );
    prev = now;

    ProcessEvents();
}
```

The application is a simple moving square. My loop looks like that and when vsync is on the whole thing just runs quite smoothly; turning it off instead causes some kind of *jumps* of the animation. I've inserted some prints and here's what I've found:

```
[...]
16
15
16
66 #
2  #
0  #
0  #
16
16
21
[...]
```

I know there are several issues with this kind of loop but none of them seem to apply to this simple example (am I wrong?). What causes this behavior and how can I overcome it?

I'm using an ATI card on a Linux system, but I'm expecting a portable explanation/solution.

Comment: Proprietary, it seems it happens only in my own applications.

Comment: SDL 1.2 or 1.3?  Does `Draw()` do a `glFinish()/glFlush()` and/or `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers()`?

Comment: `sdl-config --version` says `1.2.14`. It does `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers()` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was a lack of `glFinish()`, I've read somewhere that calls to that function are in most cases useless ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143240/opengl-glflush-vs-glfinish/2143752#2143752) or [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#glFinish_and_glFlush) for example). Well, I'm maybe misunderstanding some fundamental concepts but that worked for me and now the `Draw()` function ends with:

```
    [...]
    glFinish();
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
}
```